# How to set a selected item in Django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, variables, get

I have a `<select>` field in my Django form and what I'd like to do is set an `<option>` to `selected` depending on if the item has a certain value. The value is being passed as a `GET` variable and contains an id of a page. How can I make it `if value == <GET variable>: set option tag to selected` ?

Comment: Any reason why my solution to [your existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399339/how-to-set-a-predefined-form-value-from-a-link-in-django) on this subject was not suitable? If it wasn't, you should reply with a comment there explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

If its a form, then passing regular initial dictionary to form will suffice :

[Setting the selected value on a Django forms.ChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657607/setting-the-selected-value-on-a-django-forms-choicefield)